# ContentInset of scrollView

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uiscrollview, keyboard-events

This is my view, to the left is the view when keyboard is not showing and to the right is what I want to achieve when keyboard is showing.

[image]

All my fields are added to a scrollView that I then set constraints like this, field1 topConstraint is set to scrollView top and field4 bottomConstraint is set to scrollView bottom. all other fields are attached to the one below.

As you can see from the right most mockup, when keyboard is shown I want to readjust the view like that. So what i'm doing now is:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
       self.field2.snp_updateConstraints { make -> Void in
          make.bottom.equalTo(self.field3.snp_top).offset(8)
       }
```

with this i adjust the large space between field2 and field3, so far so good. I then go on to set the contentInset:

```
    let contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0,getKeyboardSize(notification).height, 0)

    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInset
```

but the scrollView is not adjust the way I want because field3 is still hiding half behind the keyboard.

The reason for making this post is that I clearly don't understand how contentInsets is working with scrollView and I would like to avoid setting contentOffset manually, if thats even possible.

There seems to be a problem with the constraints i'm setting. Current constraint for field4 is that i set it to be tied to the view and not scrollView bottom and I'm setting each edge of the scrollView to be tied to the view.

**Updates:** 
If i set field4 bottom constraint to be tied to the scrollView, the scrollViews height is 0, How can it not know what size it should be if I just before set the scrollView to be as big as the view itself? This has really confused me..

**Updates 2**
I'm setting the scrollView constraints like this:

```
    self.scrollView.snp_makeConstraints { make -> Void in
        make.top.equalTo(self.snp_topLayoutGuideBottom)
        make.left.right.equalTo(self.view)
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.snp_bottomLayoutGuideBottom)
    }
```

And from the UIDebugger I can see that the height of the scrollView is the same but the Y coordinate has changed to 20, but I can still not scroll in it?? Also when debugging I can set the scrollViews contentSize to be greater then the frame, that means it should be scrollable, but it isn't.

**Update 3**
I have came to the understanding now that Field1 and Field4 both need to be attached to scrollViews top and bottom. Therefore there is a difference between the scrollViews frame and scrollViews contentSize because it's works as intending when contentSize > frame the scrollView is scrollable. 
So this is big step forward for me and the only weird thing now is the contentInset.

My understanding with the contentInset is that you specify how much the view should shrink in either direction. So as it's is now i'm doing the inset with the height of the keyboard on the bottom of the scrollView but it's not scrolling, but when I'm setting the top contentInset to some random negative digit like -100 it's scrolls, why is this behaviour not achieved when the bottom inset is adjusted?

Comment: So you don't want to move your "Field 4", it should be independent from keyboard, right? I'm sorry, actually I don't have experiences in this field, so my comment probably doesn't help much. But just want to see if I understand correctly, as I'm also interested in the answer to your question.

Comment: Yea exactly, field4 should not move.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this with the following:

I made sure that Field1 and Field4 constraints was set to the scrollview, this way the scrollView was automatically able to calculate the height, and also made it possible to scroll if some content was outside the view. I then calculated the visible frame from the keyboard top and frame.

```
   func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    self.Field2.snp_updateConstraints { make -> Void in
         make.bottom.equalTo(self.Field3.snp_top)
    }

    self.Field3.snp_updateConstraints { make -> Void in
         make.bottom.equalTo(self.Field4.snp_top)
    }

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    let contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0,getKeyboardSize(notification).height + 4, 0)
    let visibleRect = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(self.scrollView.frame, contentInset)
    let scrollToOffset = max(0,self.Field4.frame.maxY - visibleRect.height)
    self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: scrollToOffset), animated: true)
 }
```

The key was after changing the constraints, I needed to invalidate the current layout and layout the views again, that way we calculations where the updated constraints where could be done correctly.